# Is there a neuter noun (word) that has different nominative and accusative form?

Tags: vocabulary, morphology

I thought neuter noun's accusative and nominative forms are always the same but is there any exception? I need any neuter word that has different nominative and accusative form. Doesn't matter if it's plural or singular.

Comment: I don't know of any such word, but I'd be very interested in the answer if there is.

Comment: Not in the Indo-European languages. Nominative-accusative syncretism is **absolute** for neuter nominal classes (nouns, adjectives, pronouns).

Comment: This is a great question, but turns out it has been asked before. That's not an issue; having this question around makes it easier for future readers to find the answer to this question. I hope you will stick around and ask more questions!